# JavaScript returning different time results with different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have this function which takes seconds as a parameter, and returns a time format string.

```
var secondstotime = function(secs) {
    var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
    t.setSeconds(secs);
    var s = t.toTimeString().substr(0, 8);
    if (secs > 86399) {
        s = Math.floor((t - Date.parse("1/1/70")) / 3600000) + s.substr(2);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Chrome and Mozilla give me two different results, I know that Chrome is right, but I don't know why Mozilla keeps adding an hour to the time string.

for example:

```
console.log(secondstotime(20000));
```

Chrome gives me `05:33:20` and Mozilla gives me `06:33:20`

I can't seem to see what the problem is and if the code is not compatible?

Comment: I've tested it and both browsers give me the same result

Comment: i have tested it aswell. and it gives me an hour extra on my firefox, what version firefox you using?

Comment: FF 20.0.1 && Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m. They both give me 05:33:20

Comment: Im using firefox 20.0, i don't know whats happening wierd!

Comment: OS? I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: Firefox 21.0 gives me 05:33:20

Comment: Check whether `console.log(new Date())` is the same. If it isn't you could have some time-offset problems.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 20.0.1, no daylight savings in my area and it displays `05:33:20`.

Comment: Qantas brings up a good possibility: what if your Firefox is operating on DST? My Chrome 28 is giving the same as your Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), and they will handle differences between browser implementations:

```
const secToTime = s => moment("2015-01-01").startOf('day')
    .seconds(s)
    .format('H:mm:ss');
```

then run:

```
secToTime(20000)
```

otherwise you should check into your implementation in the use of the Date functions, parse vs toTimeString vs constructuor